# "Operating System is not configured to use this application" when migrating a DB using the Access SQL server migration assistant

Tags: microsoft-office, sql-server, microsoft-access, data-migration, migration-assistant

I have (re)installed Microsoft SQL Server migration assistant latest version today, and i have installed Ms SQL server Management studio 18 in order to migrate my accdb access database from Access to SQL Server 19 : but at the time of uploading my DB into the migration assistant a fatal error shows up saying : "Operating System is not configured to use this application "

How do i solve this problem ?

PS : I only found this link to help out only by saying i should update office: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/error-the-operating-system-is-not-presently-configured-to-run-this-application-when-trying-to-use-access-database-engine-odbc-interfaces-fc268e32-d828-4731-86a9-3c6279285aba?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Comment: According to the URL that you provided, you may need to install the Access redistributable. You didn't mention the version of Access. You may try the following: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error after updating the migration assistant. Like the other comment said, downloading the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable fixed it.